# Quick Sort using first element as pivot

Tags: java, algorithm, pivot, quicksort, divide-and-conquer

I implemented Quick Sort by choosing the first element as pivot. it works fine for general test cases but consider a case when the array is reverse sorted for instance 5 4 3 2 1. I understand where it is throwing a runtime error. but I cant fix it correctly. Is the implementation for first element as pivot correct? Please suggest modifications.

```
 public static void quicksort(int low,int high)
  {

   if(low<high) 
   {
    int temp=0;
    int pivot=a[low];                     
    int large_index=low+1;
    int small_index=high;

    while(large_index<=small_index)
    {
      while(a[small_index]>pivot)
      small_index--;

      while(a[large_index]<pivot) 
      large_index++; 

      if(large_index<=small_index)
       {
       temp = a[large_index];
       a[large_index]= a[small_index];
       a[small_index]= temp;
       large_index++;
       small_index--;
      }
     }

     temp = a[small_index];
     a[small_index]= a[low];
     a[low]= temp;


    quicksort(low,small_index-1);
    quicksort(small_index+1,high);
   }

   }
```

Comment: perhaps try using your debugger?

Comment: At least provide the stacktrace.

Comment: Indented the code and removed unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2):

There were multiple flaws:

> a) Unnecessary swapping outside the loop
>
> temp = a[small_index]; a[small_index]= a[low]; a[low]= temp;
>
> b) The improper initialization of large_index.
>
> c) Calling the recursive function without checking the values of
>   small_index and large_index.

I have rectified them,

now the function will look like:

```
if (low < high) {
            int temp = 0;
            int pivot = a[low];
            int large_index = low;
            int small_index = high;

            while (large_index <= small_index) {
                while (a[small_index] > pivot)
                    small_index--;

                while (a[large_index] < pivot)
                    large_index++;

                if (large_index <= small_index) {
                    temp = a[large_index];
                    a[large_index] = a[small_index];
                    a[small_index] = temp;
                    large_index++;
                    small_index--;
                }
            }

            if(low < small_index)
            {
                quicksort(low, small_index);
            }
            if(large_index < high)
            {
                quicksort(large_index, high);
            }
        }
```

Now, watching the variables in your piece of code: (your code will fail in the final iteration of any given input unless the input is not sorted)

Consider the input 2,1

```
1st iteration:

pivot = 2
large_index = 1;
small_index = 1;


while1:
1<=1 -> true
    while2: 1>2 false.
    while3: 1<2 true. -> large_index++
                2nd time in while loop large_index =2 which is > the size of a.
```

> Resulting in IndexArrayOutOfBounds.

Which shows that your initialization of **large_index was wrong.**

It should have been: **large_index = low**; instead of low+1;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I got the flaws.

Comment: Could you please clarify why doesnt the array index in  while (a[large_index] < pivot) goes out if bounds?

Comment: Have updated my answer w.r.t your comments.

Comment: Upvoted for all that work untangling and neatening Ankur's code before locating the flaw. Programmers learn most from good code examples.

Comment: @BatScream Please have a look at the edited code I have posted with the same approach?

Answer (score 0):

The following loop continues on above `high`, when `large_index` already starts above the pivot and it happens that the pivot is larger than every element located after it:

```
while(a[large_index]<pivot) 
large_index++;
```

There might be other bugs, of course.

Comment: I get that. This is why I am getting a runtime error. But if put the condition for ex. while(a[large_index]<pivot && large_index<high) than I get output 2 3 4 5 1 instead of 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: That wont work. It still throws an exception for 5 4 3 2 1.

Comment: @AnkurChandra what part of **at least provide the stacktrace** don't you understand? Not everybody will try to read through your unindented code or have an eagle eye to spot your problem that easily.

Comment: Sorry Luiggi but I am a beginner here. I use Notepad++ for my codes. Could you please tell me the way to generate Stack Trace ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AnkurChandra the stacktrace is that long message that appears in the console when executing your code. And for a beginner, I recommend using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea. When you gain more experience, work with Notepad++ or another text editor.

Comment: @AnkurChandra: My previous comment was wrong, sorry.  Now deleted.

Answer (score 0):

After some attempts I was able to make the Quicksort function and it works fine now. @BatScream I have still used the small_index=low+1 in my code. So that was not a mistake I guess. And the original Quick Sort algorithm follows this mechanism. For reference please watch the lecture on QuickSort by Princeton Professor Robert Sedgewick.Please remind if there is a flaw to the edited Quick Sort Algorithm.

```
public static void quicksort(int low,int high)
 {

   if(low<high) 
   {
    int temp=0;
    int pivot=a[low];                     
    int large_index=low+1;
    int small_index=high;

    while(large_index<small_index)
  {

     while(a[large_index]<pivot) {
     if(large_index==high) 
     break;
     large_index++; 
   } 

    while(a[small_index]>pivot) 
   {
     if(small_index==low) 
     break;
     small_index--; 
   }

   if(large_index<small_index) {
     temp = a[large_index];
     a[large_index]= a[small_index];
     a[small_index]= temp;
     large_index++;
     small_index--; 
    }
  }   

    if(a[small_index]<pivot) {                               
       temp = a[small_index];
       a[small_index]= a[low];
       a[low]= temp;
  }

     if(low<small_index)                                    //Recursively sort the left half.
    {
     quicksort(low,small_index-1);
    }

    if(high>small_index)                                    //Recursively sort the right half.
   {
    quicksort(small_index+1,high);
    }
  }

  }
```